# How can I generate a variable-length list of options in PieChart?

Tags: list-manipulation, options

I would like to allow a user to manipulate the segments of a pie-chart, which is to be generated from a list of a specific format.

The code looks something like the following:

```
pieChartList = {
    {category1, 1},
    {category2, 2}
};

generatePieChart[dataList_List, plotLabel_String] :=
    Manipulate[
        PieChart[
            {category1, category2},
            PlotLabel -> plotLabel
        ],
        {{category1, 1}, 0, 10}, {{category2, 2}, 0, 10}
    ];

generatePieChart[pieChartList, "Test pie chart"]
```

As you can see, the lists are being written "manually," even though `pieChartList` contains all the information to generate the necessary structures.  Is there an elegant way to generate the manipulation list automatically?  In other words, if I were to add `{category3, 3}` to `pieChartList`, the function `generatePieChart` should pick up the new value automatically.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject variables with `##` and `& @@`:

```
generatePieChart[dataList_List, plotLabel_String] := 
  Manipulate[PieChart[dataList[[All, 1]], PlotLabel -> plotLabel], ##] & @@ 
   Thread@{dataList, 0, 10};

generatePieChart[{{category1, 1}, {category2, 2}, {category3, 3}}, "Test pie chart"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't use `_` in variable names as Mathematica will think it is a [pattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html).

`Manipulate` has the attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html) but [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Evaluate.html) can be used to get around that, allowing us to create a correct variable specification out of the data list:

```
generatePieChart[dataList : { {_Symbol, _?NumericQ} ..}, opts___] :=
 Manipulate[
  PieChart[dataList[[All, 1]], opts],
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ Map[{#, 0, 10} &, dataList]]
 ]

generatePieChart[{{c1, 1}, {c2, 2}, {c3, 1/2}}, PlotLabel -> "Test πchart"]
```

[image: pie]

`Sequence @@ Map[{#, 0, 10} &, dataList]` creates the necessary specification for `Manipulate` in this case `{{c1, 1}, 0, 10}, {{c2, 2}, 0, 10}, {{c3, 1/2}, 0, 10}`